# How to parse whole project but build only subfolder that have dependancies on other subfolder, using cmake

Tags: cmake

I'm porting a project to linux and cmake. It is part of a huge project, each subproject in a folder. I want to build only my project and its dependencies.

I can comment the other projects from the main CMakeList.txt file, but that doesn't work because there are a few dependencies to other projects (which may also depend on other projects...)

I don't want to modify all the cmake files from other projects to build only the small pieces that I need because is very error prone and time consuming. I could checkin something by mistake which I was not supposed to, for example.

My main problem is that the other projects break continuisly (almost everybody else is just working in windows, so the linux build is not taken good care of) and is slowing me down a lot.

My question is: Is there a way to tell cmake: run through all the project, but compile only what is needed to compile certain subfolder?

Comment: so use `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL`. Or specify to build just the target you want.

Comment: there are thousands of targets. I cannot add EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL to each one. Also, would need to revert that change everytime to check in the tfs repository.

Comment: That's why do `add_subdirectory(dir EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)` - and then all targets within this subdirectory are EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL. But just specify the targets you want to compile, don't compile `all`, don't you want that?

Comment: yes! this worked. I wish I had asked this before. I had not seen this option to add_subdirectory. If you write this as an answer, I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
add_subdirectory(dir EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
```

and then all targets within that subdirectory (and recursive) are by default marked with `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL`, that way they will not build by default.

You may also specify the specific targets to be build with:

```
cmake --build the_build_dir --target this_target -t another_target
```